# What is "String with Int" supposed to mean?

Tags: scala, types, type-inference

```
> val foo: PartialFunction[String, Unit] = { case i: String => }
foo: PartialFunction[String,Unit] = <function1>

> val bar: PartialFunction[Int, Unit] = { case i: Int => }
bar: PartialFunction[Int,Unit] = <function1>

> foo orElse bar
PartialFunction[String with Int,Unit] = <function1>
```

What is `String with Int?`. I don't think that's even possible.

```
> (foo orElse bar)(new String with Int)
error: illegal inheritance from final class String
  (foo orElse bar)(new String with Int)
                       ^
error: class Int needs to be a trait to be mixed in
  (foo orElse bar)(new String with Int)
                                   ^
```

Shouldn't it be `PartialFunction[Nothing,Unit]`?

Answer (score 7):

> What is String with Int?

It's an intersection type. I.e. a value of this type must be an `Int` and a `String` simultaneously.

> I don't think that's even possible.

Yes, this is an uninhabited type. However, in general if you replace `Int` and `String` with some types `A` and `B`, you'll get `PartialFunction[A with B, Unit]` and the compiler doesn't have a special case for this.

Comment: Well, it *will* allow you to pass null in, with an appropriate cast.  That doesn't help much, but it does technically work.

Comment: Ah, I would have expected that `A with B` works only if `B` is a trait.

Comment: I only tested that with Scala 2.9.2, since that's what I had handy.  Not sure if newer versions may behave differently.

Comment: @PaulDraper It can appear in `extends` only if `B` is a trait, but it's a valid type for any types `A` and `B`.

Comment: Minor note, in scala they're usually called _compound types_ rather than _intersection types_, since they don't behave like a proper set intersection would. Namely, `A with B with C` is different than `A with C with B`. See: http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~emir/bqbase/2005/02/23/compoundinter.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, as said before, it's a compound type, and it works for any two types (classes, traits), as in the following code:

```
class B
class C extends B
class D extends C

val bf: PartialFunction[B, Unit] = {case b: B => println("some b") }
val cf: PartialFunction[C, Unit] = {case c: C => println("some c") }
val g = bf orElse cf

g(new D) // some b
```

It's just that sometimes it lacks of sense in some contexts. These links may prove useful:

http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/110

http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#compound-types